# Understanding proof that a integrable function on general measure space is finite almost everywhere

Tags: measure-theory

This is the proof from Royden Chapter 18 Proposition 9
[image]

I believe we need to show that $X_\infty$ should have measure 0 for $f$ to be finite a.e, but the inequality that is shown does not prove that. We only know that the measure is less than the integral which is not enough.

Comment: We could use $n \chi_{X_\infty} \le f$ to get $n\mu(X_\infty)\le \int_X f d\mu$ for all $n$, hence $\mu(X_\infty) = 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fleshing out @Gribouillis comment, a proof is as follows:

Note that $\chi_{X_\infty} \leq f$, where $\leq$ is defined pointwise, and $f|_{X_\infty} = \infty$. So $n \chi_{X_\infty} \leq f$ on $X$, for every $n$. So we have
\begin{equation}
n \mu(X_\infty) = \int n \chi_{X_\infty} \leq \int f < \infty.
\end{equation}
Rearranging we have
\begin{equation}
\mu(X_\infty) \leq \frac{1}{n} \int f \overset{n \to \infty}{\to} 0,
\end{equation}
and we are done.

Another proof that seems to be suggested by how Royden writes it is to first show that the formula for calculating the integral of a simple function still holds when we allow the function to take on the value $\infty$. Then, we have
\begin{equation}
\int f = \int_{X\setminus X_\infty} f + \int_{X_\infty} f < \infty
\end{equation}
Then since $f|_{X_\infty} = \infty$, we would have
\begin{equation}
\int_{X_\infty} f = \infty \cdot \mu(X_\infty)
\end{equation}
which is infinite if $\mu(X_\infty)>0.$ hopefully this proof sketch helps get some feel for it.